# Keeping track of Random Column data changes in a relational database table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, rdbms

I have a PostgreSQL table (residents table) to store info's about residents in a flat complex. Say there are 50 flats. I have detailed info's about each families living here. Some of the columns are-- Resident_type(rented, owned,..), Members_count,Pets..etc.

I have more than 300 columns(try to include every tiny details) in about only 50 records. So this is like a score board, which record some state residents.

Say, something changes. family no:23 got a new dog, at march 10 2016.I will update the respective columns like Pet_count from 0 to 1, and Pet_type fron None to Dog.

You can see the events like this are happening at a random. Most time of the year nothing changes. So if i wanted to **keep track of these random change**s,what to do.?

Remember i have fewer number of records but way too many columns.

Also, i am using sqlalchemy with postgresql. But Its a general Database question.!

***My Plan B, if no body gives me better options:***

*I am gonna, split my data into two groups. Time-changeable data(like residents detais, house members,pet staus...), and permanent data(Like house number, flat location, rooms...). Them i'll make the Time-changeable columns into a table, which have a weak number column. I'm sure there's better solutions.*

Answer (score 1):

There's a design pattern here for recording change data, and I've seen two different versions of it.

The first version involves a table and a view on that table. The table is structured with all of the table columns, plus a timestamp column. There is one row per insert and update -- if family 23 got a dog, there's a row where they don't have a dog (dated back in 2013 or something), and a row where they do have a dog (dated march 10, 2016). The table contains the complete history of each family.

The view selects only the most recent row per family -- it's the snapshot of "now".

The second version of this pattern involves two tables and a trigger. The main table is just like you have currently -- one row per family. There is a trigger on that table: every time you update it, the trigger inserts a timestamped row into the second table.

In both versions, you have a table with archived changes, and a table or view of the current state.

It sounds to me like the second version would work well for you. It's better-suited to a read-often, write-occasionally setup (which is what you describe), and because you can use triggers, you're likely to be able to implement it solely on the database layer without a change in your application.

---

Here's an example of the type of sql needed for the view in the first approach:

```
CREATE VIEW current_data AS
  SELECT c.family_no, c.dog, ....
  FROM ( SELECT family_no,
                MAX(changed_timestamp) as most_recent
         FROM historical_data
         GROUP BY family_no ) h,
       historical_data c
  WHERE
    c.family_no = h.family_no AND
    c.changed_timestamp = h.most_recent;
```

Comment: Thanks, for your detailed answer. So in approach 1, the table will grow by the number of updates.Sounds like a lot of data will get duplicated, unnecessarily. But, it was ok, the problem is much simpler now. So is this "snapshot " is supported in postgreSQL( i'm suer it does..though) or even better sqlalchemy..!! And how..??  If you know this please answer that too.

Comment: The nature of keeping a history like this involves either some data duplication, or much, much more work. I've edited my response to include a sample view definition to start with if you go with the first approach.

Comment: Hey..In the context of the second approach with historical_data table, quick question~ If i have other tables which use the resident table's  PK ( resident_id)  as foreign keys, this still works,right.!

Comment: Foreign keys get a little tricky in the first scenario, but they're fine in the second -- anchor your foreign keys to the same table you do your inserts and updates on. Don't anchor your foreign keys to the history table.

Comment: So What i understood is this.~if i set up my relationships between my tables just like i normally would, and i don't have to worry about the history table, it would work behind back.IS this correct.!

Comment: Right. The only thing needed for the second approach is to set up triggers to populate the history table.

Comment: One more thing~~ Say,in the history table, i have extra Columns -mod_date, new_val, old_val got created. Now for a table1 an integer field changed, and for table 2 a string changed. There's a Type mismatch issue for columns new_val and old_val, Right.!!! Or Does History table smart enough to figure out the appropriate new_val type from corresponding old_val.??